# Accumulation Point of a Constant Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm wondering if a constant sequence can have an accumulation point? I thought my prof said no but I am unsure of the reasoning?

Comment: Based on the definition of accumulation points in "An Introduction to Complex Function Theory" (Bruce Palka), what you are alleging that your professor has said is wrong.  Given a sequence $~\langle z_n\rangle,~$ a point $~z_0~$ is an accumulation point if and only if the sequence contains a subsequence that converges to $~z_0.~$  Further, any convergent sequence **will have** exactly one accumulation point.  If every element of the sequence is a constant value $~z_0,~$ then the sequence itself is convergent, it converges to $~z_0,~$ and $~z_0~$ is the sole accumulation point of the sequence.

Comment: Re my previous comment, assuming that I stated the definitions accurately in the realm of Complex Analysis, I would speculate that parallel definitions exist in different realms, such as Real Analysis.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean by accumulation point of $A$, a point which has infinitely many elements from $A$ in its neighborhood?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur, yes! It’s in relation to a proof where if prove that ‘a’ is an accumulation point of A <=> there is a sequence of distinct points in A that converges to such ‘a’

Comment: In that case, the sequence as a set is finite and can't have infinitely many distinct points in it. A similar argument can be made for a sequence that is constant from some index onwards,, as then the set of points is again finite

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I could be mistaken.  To the best of my understanding, a set does not represent a sequence.  A sequence is an ordered list of elements, some or all of which may be repeats of previous elements.  Two elements of the sequence, that have the same value, are still considered to be distinct elements, with respect to determining whether the sequence has an accumulation point.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Keen-ameteur  My perspective is based on the reference that I cited in my initial comment.  In the realm of complex analysis, Palka first defines an accumulation point as any value $z_0,$ such that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an infinite number of elements from the sequence $\langle z_n\rangle$ that are in $\Delta(z_0,\epsilon).$  Palka then proves that $z_0$ is an accumulation point of $\langle z_n\rangle$ if and only if $\langle z_n\rangle$ contains a subsequence that converges to $z_0.$

Comment: @user2661923 I suggest you write your definition of an accumulation point in an edit to your post. You should also clarify what you mean by $\Delta(z_0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Good points.  I already added a comment with the definition of an accumulation point.  Within the realm of complex analysis, if $~z_0 \in \Bbb{C},~$ and $~r \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ then $~\Delta(z_0,r)~$ refers to the set $~\{z \in \Bbb{C} ~: ~|~z - z_0~| < r ~\}.$  Here, for $~x,y \in \Bbb{R},~$ the *norm* of the complex number $~z = x + iy~$ is symbolized as $~|~z~|~$ and represents $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$  So, if $~z_0 = x_0 + iy_0,~$ then $$|~z - z_0~| = \sqrt{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}.$$